# jquery $.each executes twice for ASP.NET/JS generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an MVC ASP.NET/JS page I have 2 tabs.

```
<div id="tabs-unactioned">
    <div id="UnactionedDiv"><div class="loading"></div></div>
</div>
<div id="tabs-actioned">
    <div id="ActionedDiv"><div class="loading"></div></div>
</div>
```

The content of these divs is dynamically inserted and both produce a div with a class of

```
grid sortable defectList
```

Now the issue is I use jquery plugin tablesorter and to initialise this I need to reference them in a unique way, but because both divs have the same class I cannot reference a specific one.

The tablesorter is initialised like so

```
$(".defectList").tablesorter();
```

So to get around this I thought I could use a $('.defectList').each() and for each element with a class of .defectList add a unique class name and then use that unique class name in the tablesorter initialisation, but for some reason the each runs twice.

Code:

```
var uniqueTableIndex = 1;
$('.defectList').each(function () {
    var obj = $(this);
    var newClassName = "unique-table-" + uniqueTableIndex;
    $(obj).addClass(newClassName);
    $('.' + newClassName).tablesorter();
    uniqueTableIndex = uniqueTableIndex + 1;
});
```

Comment: No need to wrap `obj` inside `$` once you have `var obj = $(this);`

Comment: You can use `$(".defectList").eq(0).tablesorter();` to refer first one, for second one use `$(".defectList").eq(1).tablesorter();`

Comment: I don't see anything with class `defectList` in the quoted HTML.

Comment: @TJ the HTML is dynamically inserted into ActionedDiv and UnactionedDiv

Comment: More useful, then, to quote the resulting DOM (you can copy it as HTML from the browser's devtools element view) so people can see what you're acting on. :-)

Comment: I think it is because the view is rendered twice that the code I have to initialise the tablesorter is being executed twice

Comment: @andrewb: That would make sense. But although the callback would run twice, you'd still end up with unique classnames on the elements. But you don't need them, as I explain in my answer.

Comment: Yes you are correct TJ but it seems running the initialisation twice causes the sort to behave incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

> Now the issue is I use jquery plugin tablesorter and to initialise this I need to reference them in a unique way, but because both divs have the same class I cannot reference a specific one.

Yes, you can. Modifying your initialization so we keep a variable:

```
var lists = $(".defectList").tablesorter();
```

...then `lists` is a jQuery set containing the matched elements. You can access each **raw** element via `[x]` where `x` is 0 through `lists.length - 1`:

```
list[x]
```

...or a jQuery object wrapper around each element via `eq` using those same indexes:

```
list.eq(x)
```

So for instance, if you needed for any reason to hide the first entry, you'd do:

```
list.eq(0).hide();
```